# the namespace 'DemoEntities1' could not be found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

> error on 'DemoEntities1 db = new DemoEntities1();'

```
namespace HRMS.Controllers
{
    public class FileController : Controller
    {
        DemoEntities1 db = new DemoEntities1();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, Tb_File objfile)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var filepath = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileName;
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads"), filepath);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    objfile.FileName = fileName;
                    objfile.Filepath = "~/uploads/" + filepath;
                    db.Tb_File.Add(objfile);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            return View();
        }

        //download
        public ActionResult Download()
        {
            var file = db.Tb_File.ToList();
            return View(file);
        }

        public FileResult DownloadFile(string id)
        {
            int fid = Convert.ToInt32(id);
            string filename = (from f in db.Tb_File
                               where f.Id == fid
                               select f.Filepath).First();
            return File(filename, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, filename);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: public class FileController : Controller    
      {
        DemoEntities1 db = new DemoEntities1();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

Comment: Add the reference of "DemoEntities1" and rebuild your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is DemoEntities1 in the sameproject. Probably you are missing the using statement. Currently you are in the controllers namespace and your entity might be in a different namespace.

add the following line above namespace HRMS.Controllers

```
using the namespaceforDemoentities1;
```